# greendao complex Protobuf Object Mapping

Tags: java, android, persistence, protocol-buffers, greendao

i am developing an Android-Application where complex data is synched with an server. This data is formatted in protocol buffers.

For persistence i now try to use greenDAO, because it has "protobuf support".

How do i create complex Entities without wrapper classes, so i can persist complete Protobuf Objects?

Situation now:
My buffers.java (which contains >100 different proto-buf objects) where Objects are at least as complex as:

```
Object 
 - Subobject
        - Subfield A
        - Sublist B
 - Field X
```

How can i tell the daoGenerator to take all Fields to persist? Actually im building a wrapper:

```
ObjectWrapper
  - id
  - serializedData
```

But i dont see this as an appropriate solution, because now i cant build query-filter by fields, that i dont put in the Wrapper...

Somehow i dont see another solution cause of unknown complexity and serialization issues for the daogenerator.. or is there a better solution?

thanks for the help.